# ¿Como puedo agregar objetos a una Lista en el PageModel y que la vista se actualice sin enviar el POST?

Tags: razor

[image: Tabla]

Soy nuevo en Razor Pages y quiero agregar un producto a una lista que se encuenta en el PageModel y desplegar la lista en una tabla, pero que al momento de agregar un producto a la lista la seccion de la tabla se actualice.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! intentaste algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eso se realiza mediante `javascript` solo haz referencia a tus elementos donde dice `col 1` y `col 2` es un ejemplo simple.

```js
$('#add').on('click', function(){
  html = '<tr><td>col 1</td>';
  html += '<td>col 2</td></tr>';
  
  $('tbody').append(html)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">añadir nuevo</button>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```